# HTML5 datalist + Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Faced with need to create auto-complite and tried to use datalist like a fondation for it. Spend a lot of time - and close it. Built it with `<select>`and`<input>`.
Have two very regular question - but still have no normal answer.
Is it possible to add some style to `<datalist>` ? or using angular build control of the count options inside `<datalist>` and use ng-click on this  inside `datalist`?

Comment: Not able to understand your question. Please add a plunker/fiddle to explain your query, so that we can assist you

Comment: made some fixes. Sorry

Comment: I don't understand, kindly create a fiddle